# Cuda programming-passing nested structs to kernels

Tags: c, parallel-processing, cuda

I'm new to CUDA C and I'm trying to parallelize the following piece of code of the slave_sort function, which you will realize that is already parallel to work with posix threads..
I have the following structs:

```
typedef struct{
   long densities[MAX_RADIX];
   long ranks[MAX_RADIX];
   char pad[PAGE_SIZE];
}prefix_node;

struct global_memory {
   long Index;                             /* process ID */
   struct prefix_node prefix_tree[2 * MAX_PROCESSORS];
} *global;

void slave_sort(){
         .
         .
         .
long *rank_me_mynum;
struct prefix_node* n;
struct prefix_node* r;
struct prefix_node* l;
         .
         .
MyNum = global->Index;
global->Index++;
n = &(global->prefix_tree[MyNum]);
     for (i = 0; i < radix; i++) {
        n->densities[i] = key_density[i];
        n->ranks[i] = rank_me_mynum[i];
     }
     offset = MyNum;
     level = number_of_processors >> 1;
     base = number_of_processors;
     while ((offset & 0x1) != 0) {
       offset >>= 1;
       r = n;
       l = n - 1;
       index = base + offset;
       n = &(global->prefix_tree[index]);
       if (offset != (level - 1)) {
         for (i = 0; i < radix; i++) {
           n->densities[i] = r->densities[i] + l->densities[i];
           n->ranks[i] = r->ranks[i] + l->ranks[i];
         }
       } else {
         for (i = 0; i < radix; i++) {
           n->densities[i] = r->densities[i] + l->densities[i];
         }
       }
       base += level;
       level >>= 1;
}
```

Mynum is the number of processors. I want after passing the code to kernel, Mynum to be`represented by blockIdx.x`.The problem is that i get confused with the structs. I don't know how to pass them in the kernel. Can anyone help me?

Is the following code right?

```
__global__ void testkernel(prefix_node *prefix_tree, long *dev_rank_me_mynum, long *key_density,long radix)

int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDimx.x;
prefix_node *n;
prefix_node *l;
prefix_node *r;
long offset;
     .
     .
     .
n = &prefix_tree[blockIdx.x];
if((i%numthreads) == 0){
    for(int j=0; j<radix; j++){
        n->densities[j] = key_density[j + radix*blockIdx.x];
        n->ranks[i] = dev_rank_me_mynum[j + radix*blockIdx.x];
    }
    .
    .
    .
 } 


int main(...){

    long *dev_rank_me_mynum;
    long *key_density;
    prefix_node *prefix_tree;
    long radix = 1024;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_rank_me_mynum, radix*numblocks*sizeof(long));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&key_density, radix*numblocks*sizeof(long));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&prefix_tree, numblocks*sizeof(prefix_node));

    testkernel<<<numblocks,numthreads>>>(prefix_tree,dev_runk_me_mynum,key_density,radix);
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the CUDA code you have and explain exactly which part of the code doesn't work? As it stands, this isn't much of a question.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host API code you have posted in your edit looks fine. The `prefix_node` structure only contains statically declared arrays, so all that is needed is a single `cudaMalloc` call to allocate memory for the kernel to work on. Your method of passing `prefix_tree` to the kernel is also fine.

The kernel code, although incomplete and containing a couple of obvious typos, is another story. It seems that your intention is to only have a single thread per block operate on one "node" of the `prefix_tree`. That will be terribly inefficient and utilise only a small portion of the GPU's total capacity. For example why do this:

```
prefix_node *n = &prefix_tree[blockIdx.x];
if((i%numthreads) == 0){
    for(int j=0; j<radix; j++){
        n->densities[j] = key_density[j + radix*blockIdx.x];
        n->ranks[j] = dev_rank_me_mynum[j + radix*blockIdx.x];
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

when you could to this:

```
prefix_node *n = &prefix_tree[blockIdx.x];
for(int j=threadIdx.x; j<radix; j+=blockDim.x){
    n->densities[j] = key_density[j + radix*blockIdx.x];
    n->ranks[j] = dev_rank_me_mynum[j + radix*blockIdx.x];
}
```

which coalesces the memory reads and uses as many threads in the block as you choose to run, rather than just one and should be many times faster as a result. So perhaps you should rethink your strategy of directly trying to translate the serial C code you posted into a kernel....